# how to solve "missing shared object" w/o root right

Tags: linux, object, shared

Recently I want to run a statistical software SCILAB on our Linux server. I downloaded the software and ran the binary (the software manual says no need to install), but I got this error message:

"scilab-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libXss.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

I don't have a root right on the server and I don't think the administrator will install the missing packages for me. Is there are way to solve this problem? The server seems running Fedora or RedHat, and has "yun" "rpm".

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you can get a compatible libXss.so on the system under your account, try adding it to your library path

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/solib
```

and try running the application.